# Jquery chart variable updation from Smarty

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

My dashboard page contains a chart, which is a java script chart.js, which also contains the variable needed to draw the chart on the page. The variables are picked from a mysql script written in PHP. I want to update the chart.js variable using smarty to show on the dashboard page. Should i shift the variable from chart.js to dahboard page and update from smarty, or there is a better way doing this. Please suggest.

Comment: Is there a way to update supporting css and js files of a webpage before the actual dispaly() in smarty.

Comment: Please add some more explanation of the problem. It's a bit unclear atm. Do you use a Ajax call from the JS to a PHP file that outputs something using Smarty? Is the JS file itself created via PHP using smarty? How does the variable in question get into the JS file?

Comment: Sorry for delay, its static and i m not using ajax. It is a single file rendered through Smarty contains the js also. Is it possible to separate the js and create via php using Smarty.